# "Kaputt gehen" meaning "to become defect" in a more formal way

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expression, synonym

The expression "kaputt gehen" for the meaning "to become defect" is somewhat colloquial, and I would like to express it more formal, as in a letter to report a problem.

> Der Behälter ist gerade **kaputt gegangen**, er hat ein Leck bekommen.

"Wurde gerade defekt" does not sound right.

Is there a synonym or a similar expression matching that meaning?

Comment: Notice that _kaputt gehen_ ≠ _kaputtgehen_. In your example sentence only the latter makes sense.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich - Do you mean it should be "Der Behälter ist gerade kaputtgegangen, er hat ein Leck bekommen."? What is the difference?

Comment: yes, this is what I mean. _kaputt gehen_ = to walk in a defect way, _kaputtgehen_ = to become defect.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich - Right, that makes sense. Though I suspect that "kaputt gehen" is practically used in both meanings. That works only because "Gang" is seldom described as "kaputt".

Comment: Man kann hier auch auf Deutsch fragen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make it formal, I'd go with *"unbrauchbar geworden"*, something like:

> Aufgrund eines Lecks ist der Behälter gerade *unbrauchbar geworden*.

or in the original sentence

> Der Behälter ist gerade **unbrauchbar geworden**, er hat ein Leck bekommen.

Comment: "außer Betrieb" does not work because it could be reversed, but "unbrauchbar geworden" is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I rewrote the answer to show "unbrauchbar geworden", the right expression, as answer. It is under your name, so edit or revert as you see fit.

Comment: "unbrauchbar geworden" is too special. Voted down.

Comment: @äüö I'm curious as to why would you think it is "too special". Als ob "betriebstauglich" weniger special wäre...

Comment: @Dan: mit "unbrauchbar geworden" bezieht man sich nur auf den Aspekt, ob das kaputte Ding noch verwendet werden kann oder nicht. Ein Synonym für "kaputt" ist für mich vielmehr "defekt" oder "beschädigt".

Comment: Achso, du meinst etwa, es gibt kaputte Dinge, die dennoch noch zu gebrauchen sind?

Comment: @Dan: Wenn ich sage, dass das Meer salzig ist, ist es trotzdem kein Synonym für nass, auch wenn es kein nichtsalziges Meer gibt ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here are various well-formed sentences to express *Der Behälter ist kaputtgegangen* in more formal language:

> Der Behälter ist defekt. Es tritt Flüssigkeit aus.
>
> Der Behälter hat einen Defekt. Er leckt.
>
> Der Behälter ist beschädigt. Er hat ein Leck.
>
> Der Behälter hat eine Beschädigung erlitten. Es ist ein Leck aufgetreten.
>
> Der Behälter ist nicht mehr betriebstauglich. Wir haben festgestellt, dass er leckt.
>
> Wir haben eine Havarie am Behälter. Es sind etliche Leckagen aufgetreten.

Note that *Havarie* suggest really large damage of a really large piece of equipment. You would not have a *Havarie* with your bycycle. You could have one with your ship or your petrochemical plant.

And here are expressions in very casual language:

> Der Behälter ist am Arsch. Er leckt wie die Sau.
>
> Der Behälter ist im Eimer. Der hält das Wasser nicht mehr.

Comment: I know am Arsch in the sense of being fucked or screwed, while *im* Arsch refers to be broken (same as *im* Eimer).

Comment: this should be marked as the real answer

Comment: "im Eimer ...  hält das Wasser nicht" is seriously funny.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage would be "der Behälter erlitt einen Defekt".  If you use this outside of written speech, however, people will stare at you.  "kaputt" is a whole lot more acceptable (and missing formal status just by a hair's breadth) in German than the corresponding loan term "kaput" (via Yiddish) in English.  Something like "Es kann ja wohl nicht sein, daß der Behälter schon nach einem Monat kaputt ist." would be a perfectly acceptable utterance and more rather than less formal than using "hinüber" (a short paraphrase of the colloquial "über den Jordan") instead of "kaputt".